# powercfg won't produce battery report or sleep study

Tags: windows-10, battery, sleep

I'm trying to diagnose a potential issue with my (fully up to date) Surface Pro 6. When I put it to sleep overnight it drops about 15-25% battery.

In my investigation, I wanted to look at both

```
powercfg /batteryreport
powercfg /sleepstudy
```

however, when I run these commands from an elevated cmd prompt I get the response

```
Unable to perform operation.  An unexpected error (0xb7) has occurred:  Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
```

while true, battery-report.html, does exist... this doesn't matter on any other machine - it just overwrites it.

my powercfg works fine, if I run

```
powercfg /energy
```

it outputs the expected

```
Enabling tracing for 60 seconds...
Observing system behavior...
Analyzing trace data...
Analysis complete.

Energy efficiency problems were found.

8 Errors
8 Warnings
42 Informational

See C:\WINDOWS\system32\energy-report.html for more details.
```

This contains a bunch of **USB Suspend:USB Device not Entering Selective Suspend** reports that I think, are from my Surface Dock. Run it unplugged and they aren't present.

Regardless, this isn't the problem I'm trying to solve here.

**Update**

`powercfg /systemsleepdiagnostics` = works...

`powercfg /systempowerreport` = fails (file exists error again)

`powercfg /srumutil`  = fails with...

```
Error: SruUpdateStats failed
Completed with status 183 (0x000000b7)
Unable to perform operation.  An unexpected error (0x1f) has occurred:  A device attached to the system is not functioning.
```

**Summary**

These are broken...

```
powercfg /batteryreport
powercfg /sleepstudy
powercfg /systempowerreport
powercfg /srumutil
```

while these are not...

```
powercfg /energy
powercfg /systemsleepdiagnostics
```

Comment: did you find a solution? same here, no idea so far.

Comment: @FalcoAlexander no, I never got to the bottom of this, gave up.

Comment: Running the PowerShell as an administrator solved the issue for me

Comment: Running as admin, `/srumutil` and `/batteryreport` give errors, while the rest do work. Note that this is my desktop, so the battery report is not expected to give anything useful (but you would expect that the tool is able to expect that condition, instead of "Unexpected error (0x10d2) has occurred."