# Launching mspaint and wordpad fail with "Unable to create new document"

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-paint, wordpad

Launching mspaint or wordpad fails with this prompt. This happens when they are launched from any directory, with or without arguments.

My system is Windows 10 version 2004. I've installed some updates recently, but `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` didn't report any error.

I am aware of [this post regarding wordpad](https://superuser.com/questions/1552500/wordpad-blah-txt-says-unable-to-create-new-document). But in my case, all wordpad.exe instances fail with this error.

Any suggestion as to how to troubleshoot will be appreciated.

Comment: It might be related that I've also encountered the problem of [`powercfg /batteryreport` cannot create a file when that file already exists`](https://superuser.com/questions/1472017/powercfg-wont-produce-battery-report-or-sleep-study).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Open Settings, Apps, Apps & features, Optional features.
2. Select Microsoft Paint and click Uninstall.
3. Select WordPad and click Uninstall
4. Click the `Add a feature` option.
5. Add (reinstall) Microsoft Paint and WordPad one by one.

[image: Screenshot 01]

[image: Screenshot 02]

Comment: Step 1 should be, "Open Settings, Apps, Apps & features, Optional features."

Comment: I cannot believe that Microsoft will have such a bug.  (I have a rresh re-installation of Win 10 and come across the same problem ! cannot launch notepad/wordpad/mspaint !!!!  ). Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a batch script for this:

```
@echo off
dism /Online /Remove-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.Windows.WordPad~~~~0.0.1.0
dism /Online /Remove-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.Windows.MSPaint~~~~0.0.1.0
ping localhost -n 4 >nul 2>&1
dism /Online /add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.Windows.WordPad~~~~0.0.1.0
dism /Online /add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.Windows.MSPaint~~~~0.0.1.0
Exit /b 0
```

Don't forget to run it as administrator